# Catkin BFL build fails - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Thanks for reading my question.

I'm attempting to install ROS on Ubuntu 12.04 on a Pandaboard ES REV B.

I've followed the manual here to install from source.

At the moment, I am at step 3.1.3 Building the Catkin Workspace.  I run the command

```
$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
```

from my directory:

```
$ /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws 


pandaboardalpha@pandaboardalpha:/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated  --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
Base path: /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws
Source space: /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated
Devel space: /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated
Install space: /opt/ros/groovy
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  traversing packages in topological order:
~~  - bfl (plain cmake)
~~  - catkin
[..]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Warning: packages or cmake arguments have changed, forcing cmake
==> Processing plain cmake package: 'bfl'
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/bfl'
==> cmake /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/src/bfl -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy
/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/bfl
==> make -j2 -l2 in '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/bfl'
==> make install in '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/bfl'
==> Generating an env.sh
<== Failed to process package 'bfl': 
  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
Command failed, exiting.
pandaboardalpha@pandaboardalpha:/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws$
```

I just wondered if anyone else had this error.  The bfl package actually installs properly, since I found it in /opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated.

I guess the problem is in the generation of "env.sh", but I don't know enough about it to know.

The end goal is to install openni on the board an interface with the Kinect, so if there's a simpler better way to go about it, I'm all ears!

Thank you for reading this far!!!

Best,
Nathan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56962/catkin-bfl-build-fails---%27nonetype%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27rfind%27/) by [ND Guthrie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4345/nd-guthrie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok, the bug is actually in catkin 0.5.63, we're about to release a fix I think.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-04**:
https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/340

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-03-04**:
Also follow this issue maybe, in case you get the same problem: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/374

**Comment by [ND Guthrie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4345/nd-guthrie/) on 2013-03-04**:
YES - I have 'build' and 'devel' folders appear also.  Will run more tests and update soon.  Thanks!